# why does Kernel Density Estimator need a fitting step?

Tags: scikit-learn, cluster-analysis, kernel-density

I am using Kernel Density Estimator (KDE) to do a grouping of one-dimension array of numbers. All the tutorials of Scikit's KernelDensity module does this in two steps:

1: Do a fitting on a training dataset.

2: calculate the KDE for your interested data.

Here is the code:

```
from sklearn.neighbors import KernelDensity

dataset = np.array([1.33, 0.3, 0.97, 1.1, 0.1, 1.4, 0.4])

# KernelDensity requires 2D array
dataset = dataset[:, np.newaxis]

# fit KDE to the dataset
kde = KernelDensity(kernel='gaussian', bandwidth=0.1).fit(dataset)

# x-value range for plotting KDE
x_range = np.linspace(1, 10000, num=600)

# compute the log-likelihood of each sample
log_density = kde.score_samples(x_range[:, np.newaxis])
```

I don't understand why we need `.fit` step in the process. Theoretically, we only need a given array of numbers and then use KDE to do the calculations.

Comment: `I don't understand why we need .fit step in the process. Theoretically, we only need a given array of numbers` I'm not sure I understand the question. .fit() is how you give the array of numbers to the kernel density estimator. How would you give it the array if not through .fit()?

Comment: `log_density = kde.score_samples(x_range[:, np.newaxis])` is how we give the array to KDE. Maybe I am wrong understanding how this really works. Could you show me an example how to use KDE properly, suppose my array is [
        0.17714119,
        0.1911622,
        0.2011621,
        0.2011921,
        0.2021621,
        0.2061621,
        0.20922184,
        0.21022184,
        0.21122184,
        0.21922184,
        0.24380147,
        0.25328255,
    ]?

Comment: Do you want to fit the KDE to those points, or do you want to know the value of the KDE at those points?

Comment: It might help to explain what you expect to use this KDE for. But I think the confusion is more about the statistical method than programming, so you'd probably get better answers at stats.SE or datascience.SE.

Comment: My intension was to cluster a given 1-dimensional array of float numbers. For example, given [3,5,2,6, 10,14,15], I can cluster them into two subgroups: [3,5,2,6] and [10, 14, 15]